# How to remove animation in SwiftUI NavigationLink when tapping specific views

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

There is a favorite button in my view which has NavigationLink. Each time I press the favorite button, opacity animations also shows. I don't want to show any animation while I tapping the favorite buttons.
I know how to remove animation at whole view, but I hope the animation works when I press outside of favorite buttons.

```
HStack {
    Image(systemName: "a.book.closed.fill")
        
    Text(book.name)
        
    Spacer()
        
    FavoriteButton(isFavorite: $isFavorite)
        .onChange(of: isFavorite) { newValue in
            book.isFavorite = newValue
            model.saveData()
        }
}
```

This is my book row view

```
ScrollView {
    ForEach(model.savedBookEntities) { elem in
        NavigationLink() {
            VocaView(book: elem)
        } label: {
            BookRow(book: elem)
        }
        .contextMenu() {
            // Some context menus
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my ScrollView in NavigationView.

```
Button(action: { isFavorite.toggle() })
{
    if isFavorite {
        Image(systemName: "star.fill")
        }
    else {
        Image(systemName: "star")
    }
}
```

This is FavoriteButton's code

[image: How the animation look like]

Comment: I don't see any animation here? What animation? Also, please include your FavoriteButton code here.

Comment: @tail The animation shown by NavigationLink. The default animation that blinks when tapping a linking view.

Comment: There is no blink or opacity animation like your comment and description. Maybe you meant slide animation. Please include reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

Animation happens on animatable parameter changing. If `FavoriteButton` does not change anything else inside, then try to disable animation for `isFavorite`, like

```
HStack {
    Image(systemName: "a.book.closed.fill")
        
    Text(book.name)
        
    Spacer()
        
    FavoriteButton(isFavorite: $isFavorite)
        .onChange(of: isFavorite) { newValue in
            book.isFavorite = newValue
            model.saveData()
        }
        .animation(nil, value: isFavorite)   // << here !!
}
//.animation(nil, value: isFavorite)   // << or here !!
```

also `book.isFavorite` might affect, so if above would not work for you try the same with `book.isFavorite`.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work for me. I tried at the NavigationLink like that, but opacity still changes in a moment without being animated.

Comment: Then I need minimal reproducible example, guessing will not help here.

Answer (score 0):

```swift
@State var action: Int?

ViewEmitNavigation()
    .onTapGesture {
        action = 1 // make action equal to tag
    }
    .overlay {
        NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView(), tag: 1, selection: $action) {}.opacity(0) // make it invisible
    }
```

Now the blink effect on tap just disappeared